# Comparing datetime values in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

This question might be a duplicate but I’ve tried all the answers of the other questions and none of the answers did help.

I'm trying to compare a datetime value against a static one ( I need every record with a date lager then 1/1/2016 )

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Cursusoverzicht as
SELECT tblBijeenkomst.bijeenkomstdatum, tblCursussen.cursus_id, tblCursussen.cursustitel
FROM tblCursussen
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblCursusDocenten] on [dbo].[tblCursusDocenten].[cursus_id] = [dbo].[tblCursussen].[cursus_id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblBijeenkomst] on [dbo].[tblBijeenkomst].[docent_id] = [dbo].[tblCursusDocenten].[docent_id]
WHERE tblBijeenkomst.bijeenkomstdatum > '2016/1/1 00:00:00:000'
```

This keeps returning 0 records, anyone any idea?

Sorry for the dutch names

Comment: Data type for tblBijeenkomst.bijeenkomstdatum column?

Comment: tblBijeenkomst.bijeenkomstdatum is a datetime

Comment: Try with changing `2016/1/1 00:00:00:000` to `2016/1/1 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: @diiN_ still no results

Comment: You get results without the `WHERE`?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine up untill the `WHERE` statment

Comment: Substitute `'2016/1/1 00:00:00:000'` with `'20160101 00:00:00.000'`. If that doesn't work show us at least one line in the table that has a date/time that is strictly bigger than that date/time

Comment: declare a variable `@DateTimeConst datetime = '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' ` and `select @DateTimeConst ` to check its value before you execute the query

Comment: OMG i'm so stupid the results are only in 2005 and 2006 not 2016 so it's quite obvieus that i don't get any results. I wanne thank everybody for there time and sorry for my stupidity ;-)

Comment: It is best to format dates in locale-independent formats. ISO 8601 was made just for that. It defines following formats: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]` and `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]`. The parts between rectangular brackets are optional. The `T` in the first format is the character `T`. Read more on this here: [datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are almost there:

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE Cursusoverzicht as
         SELECT tblBijeenkomst.bijeenkomstdatum
            ,tblCursussen.cursus_id
            ,tblCursussen.cursustitel
           FROM tblCursussen
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblCursusDocenten] 
           on
                [dbo].[tblCursusDocenten].[cursus_id] 
             = [dbo].[tblCursussen].[cursus_id]
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblBijeenkomst] 
            on 
                 [dbo].[tblBijeenkomst].[docent_id] 
              = [dbo].[tblCursusDocenten].[docent_id]
            and tblBijeenkomst.bijeenkomstdatum >          
                    CONVERT (date, '2016-01-01T00:00:00:000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the format of your datetime to 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000.  This is the SQL Server default format.

You can test this for yourself using the [GETDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188383.aspx) function.  This returns the current date and time as a [DATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187819.aspx).

```
SELECT
   GETDATE() AS FormatTest
;
```

Returns

```
FormatTest
----------------
2016-01-29 10:40:20.567
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format datetime for this condition

```
WHERE tblBijeenkomst.bijeenkomstdatum > CONVERT(DATETIME, 'YOUR DATE EXPRESSION', STYLE)
```

For `STYLE` parameter, you must see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_4

For example:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '15.01.01', 2)
```